# Angular2+ using .getElementsByClassName() returns empty selection though existent

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a fairly simple question maybe, but I can't find an answer to it. I also searched previous questions but it seems not to work....

I have on my template in angular a large amount of text inside a `div` and some parts are wrapped with a `span` and those have the class **highlight**. Now I simply want to select them all when I press on a button. I need all the spans and do sth with them later.

I tried:

```
const elm = (this.el as any).getElementsByClassName('.highlight');
console.log('elmens: ', elm);
for (let i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  console.log('HTML ELM: ', elm[i]);
}
```

Also with:

```
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('.highlight');
```

This both only returns me an empty selection, although they are existent. I even tried it on the browser console. I know I could use jQuery maybe, but I don't want to include it for such simple tasks.

Maybe you know what I am doing wrong???

***I am using:***

- Angular: 7.0.0
- Angular-cli: 7.0.2
- Typescript: 3.1.3

Comment: Then the question would be, when does your logic get triggerred. After or before the view is rendered?

Comment: _“and those [spans] have the class .highlight”_ - do they really? Do they not perhaps rather have the class `highlight`? The leading dot is for the CSS class selector, but getElementsByClassName has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I changed the description. I think I found the right answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
const elements= (<HTMLCollection>document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name_without_dot'));

console.log(elements)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know I have to remove the dot.... However, it works now though it doesn't seem to find everything.

Answer (score 2):

I would look to avoid using this technique within the angular framework as it is not recommended to interact with the DOM in this way. They have appropriate alternatives. Interacting with the DOM can introduce Performance implications and is bad practice.

Instead you could look into using `@viewchildren` for this problem. 
Docs [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Which would suggest each element you want to get, in your case the `spans`

```
<span #myNewId>text</span> 
<span #myNewId>text snippet 2</span>
```

Could be accessed in the controller with the following

```
@ViewChildren('myNewId')public mySpans: ElementRef;
```

This should give you all the same functionality without having to interact directly with the DOM. `mySpans` will then be an array of the spans marked with the `#myNewID`.

This should also allow you access your elements in regards to your question, as they are bound the variables in the class.

Comment: Generally the way I would do it too thank you! But i have the content dynamically generated. Thats why I cant assign template refs to it. But thank you for your time you took to answer this.

Comment: your welcome, would have a read around though about Angular and DOM. I think you could use refs and apply the # when content is generated and just check the viewChildren exist before trying to interact with them, but if your problem is solved all good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your child views are not initialized and you try to play with DOM before elements are rendered to the browser. try to use Angular hooks and then call you code. Like

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {

   ...
   const elm = (this.el as any).getElementsByClassName('.highlight');
   console.log('elmens: ', elm);
   for (let i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
     console.log('HTML ELM: ', elm[i]);
   }
   ...

}
```

Comment: If you try to get elements to early ( not in proper hook) they are not there yet. You can also chec other hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

you can also check `ngAfterViewInit()` hook

Comment: I am sure I have the view initialized cause this happens only on user input. However, I think I found the answer.